# ASP.NET MembershipProvider encryption/decryption

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I have some questions on the MembershipProvider in .Net that I have been unable to find clear answers to.

- What type of encryption is used, AES?
- The method *EncryptPassword*, can it handle any salt, or do I simply add that before passing it?
- The method *DecryptPassword* - can you really decrypt the password?  Isn't that a poor practice to be able to do?

Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[add Element for providers for membership (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whae3t94.aspx)

- **enablePasswordRetrieval attribute**: "Specifies whether the membership provider instance supports password retrieval. If true, the membership provider instance supports password retrieval  The default is false for both the SQL and Active Directory providers."
- **passwordFormat attribute**: "One of the MembershipPasswordFormat values that indicates the format for storing passwords in the membership data store. The default is Hashed."

  - *Hashed*: "Passwords are encrypted one-way using the SHA1 hashing algorithm.
    You can specify a hashing algorithm different than the SHA1 algorithm using the hashAlgorithmType attribute."
  - *Encrypted*: "Encrypted Passwords are encrypted using the encryption settings determined by the machineKey Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema) element configuration."

So, by default the SqlMembershipProvider uses a hashed (one-way) password that is hashed with SHA1.  Hashing the passwords doesn't use the EncryptPassword/DecryptPasswords methods, but no, you cannot manually pass salts to Encryption/Encoding of passwords (it salts them for you).